# Two arrays sorted to see if they have the same value, but it only picks up that there are 2/3 values that are the same in the arrays

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I don't know why only 2 out of 3 of values are showing that they are the same in my code, is there something I am missing?

```
def occurInBoth(B,A):
    occured = 0
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] == B[i]: 
            occured += 1

    return occured



A = [5,12,31,7,25]
sorted(A)
A.sort()
print(A)
B = [4,12,7,31,42,8]
sorted(B)
B.sort()
print(B)
occured = occurInBoth(B,A)
print(occured)
```

Could you please advise me?

Comment: The fact that the two are sorted does *not* mean that both these values will occur at the same index.

Comment: The calls to `sorted` aren't doing anything because they don't modify the list, and you're not assigning the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a logical error in your algorithm. If two lists are sorted, that does *not* mean that the items will occur at the same index.

Indeed, take the sorted lists in your example:

```
A = [5, 7, 12, 25, 31]
B = [4, 7,  8, 12, 31, 42]
```

As you can see `12` occurs in both lists, but not at the same index.

You can however make use of the fact that the lists are sorted:

```
def occurInBoth(a, b):
    occured = i = j = 0
    while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
        if a[i] < b[j]:
            i += 1
        elif a[i] > b[j]:
            j += 1
        else:
            occurred += 1
            i += 1
            j += 1
```

Comment: Oh I see because it isn't in the same index number the complied code thinks they don't match :D